# Одинаковое название для переменной и класса

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Допустимо использовать одинаковое название для класса и переменной в примере `class settingsBlock` и объект `let settingsBlock`?
Или название объекта не должно быть в camelCase?

```js
class settingsBlock extends elementByClass {
    open () {
        this.classList.toggle('settings_opened');
    }
}

let settingsBlock = new settingsBlock('settings');

document.getElementsByClassName('settings-button')[0].onclick = function () {
    settingsBlock.open();
};
```

Ткните, пожалуйста, в документацию. Все примеры, которые видел используют простые слова типа "menu, settings, button", для обозначения переменной, что неудобно в больших проектах

Comment: Вот неплохое соглашение по наименованию [соглашение](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/)

Comment: @Mikl не понял, зачем вы предложили БЭМ? речь идет о js

Comment: увидел settings-button и settings_opened в одном коде и решил что автору будет полезно и с этим разобраться

Comment: @Mikl а что с ними не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такое недопустимо.

При создании класса, либо объявлении переменной с помощью let либо const с именем которое уже существует, будет брошено исключение:

> Identifier '' has already been declared

И проблема не в *camel-case*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50449/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy------).

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы объявляете переменную, функцию или что-либо ещё, то создается область видимости. Область видимости, это грубо говоря объект, который хранит ссылки на объекты создаваемые внутри этой области.

Так вот эта область видимости так же как и `Object` все значения хранит в качестве свойств, для ключей которых используется строка. Это означает что и переменная и функция будет выглядеть примерно так -

```
var propName = 5;

function functionName(){};

{ propName: propName, functionName: functionNane }
```

Так же нужно помнить что имя переменной это ссылка на объект и из этого следует что в одной области видимости не может быть два одинаковых ключа - две одинаковых ссылки.

И отдельно про именование - в `js` для именования переменных, типов, констант и методов принято использовать `java style` -

- var propName
- let propName
- const CONST_NAME
- function functionName(){}
- class ClassName{}

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50455/discussion-on-answer-by-olmerdale------).